# Assigning a delegate to a background job for dropbox upload

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, dropbox, background-process

I am using Dropbox's SDK API V1 to upload files from my iOS app. The files aren't loading in real time, but rather I push them into a queue, and they get uploaded in the background.

I can't figure out for the life of me how to take DB RestClient delegate and make it respond to a completion/failure event that happens in the background. Is that even possible?

It seems (and I am new here), that delegates are meant to respond to live events on screen. Is that even an option to assign them to anything other than a UI element/view?

*Update: Adding some description of what the code looks like.*

There is a lot of code and it's hard for me to tell what's relevant for this question.

I am using `PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges()` which has a completion handler.

On success, I send an image upload request via `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` method.

Dropbox API has this method `dropboxRestClient.uploadFile(filename, toPath: pathOnDropbox, withParentRev: nil, fromPath: localFileUrl)`

In all the examples that I've seen, `dropboxRestClient.delegate` was assigned to a UIViewController of some sort, and never to anything else.

So I am not sure how to assign it correctly, so that it recognizes events that happen in this queue.

Comment: No, delegates are meant to respond in any way that's appropriate for the function they serve. You'l need to post the relevant code if you want specific help. I haven't used the DB API before.

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. There is a lot of code and I don't know what's actually relevant to find a solution. If you've seen examples of how delegates are used outside of View Controllers, I'd appreciate a link! tnx!

Comment: Have you tried setting the delegate to another class? The `dropboxRestClient.delegate` needs to be set to a class, but I don't know if it specifically needs to be a view controller.

Comment: @LeahCulver I tried to do the DB delegate in the same UI view that the upload methods were, and it all works, but as soon as I split them, something doesn't connect. That said, I tried another class, and on its own, the class wouldn't accept DBRestClientDelegate as an inheritance. However, as soon as you add ```myNewTestClass: UIViewController,  DBRestClientDelegate``` it allows me to inherit from DB delegate. But, it still doesn't work :)

Comment: Long story short, I reorganized my app so every DB related thing could be in one controller and now everything works. Not ideal, but it was faster than trying to figure this out properly. Onwards to better things!